# Auto move in google spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet

I have a google spreadsheet contains 2 sheets, sheet a and sheet b. In Sheet A, cell A1 to A5 populate some data automatically. I need these data to be moved to Sheet B one by one vertically one below one. The issue is Sheet A produces data in A to A5 as soon as we move the existing data to Sheet b, again i have to copy-paste that data to Sheet b. Can we make this automatically?

Like. As soon as data comes in sheet 2 A1 to a5 cell, it should automatically move to sheet B below the existing data.

Answer (score 0):

You can point cells from one sheet to another with providing sheet name and cell name. The formula filled cell will be updated automatically

```
='SHEET2'!A1
```

Comment: Then what would be if comes new data? Need `google script` like `VBA` on windows.

Comment: Cell will be updated dynamically. Why you need to have a script to copy cell content from one sheet to another ?

Comment: Am getting error as "Error
Circular dependency detected. To resolve with iterative calculation, see File > Spreadsheet Settings." Because as soon as the data move to sheet 2, it should delete from sheet a

Comment: Since you did not mention that you should delete the value after you copy-paste, i tried to create a solution just for copy-paste action. At that moment @Harun24HR is right, you need a script for those actions.